# Android HTTP POST sending json

Tags: android, json, http-post

```
{"method": "setActiveApp", "params": [{"uri":"localapp://webappruntime?        url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8125/active","data":""}], "id": 1}
```

When trying to send the above json data in HTTP post I always get ILLEGAL JSON response from the server. Actually wireshark logs show that instead of the above data, the below json body(extra " present after "params": ") is being sent.How can I resolve this issue?

```
{"method": "setActiveApp", "params": "[{"uri":"localapp://webappruntime?        url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8125/active","data":""}]", "id": "1"}
```

Comment: post your code how you are sending data to server.?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. Add some try/catch by taste.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

final String CODEPAGE = "UTF-8";
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(yourUrl);
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(yourJson.toString(), CODEPAGE));
HttpResponse resp = null;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
resp = httpclient.execute(post);
```

Comment: I am doing exactly the same. But the problem is that I see extra " in the data being sent and the server responds back with ILLEGAL JSON. How can I fix this?

Comment: I see. You've got incorrect json.
Check it out: object "params" has String with <">'s. Replace all <"> with <'> like this: {
   "method":"setActiveApp",
   "params":"[{'uri':'localapp://webappruntime?url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8125/active','data':''}]",
   "id":1
}
Then check your json string here: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/